# Remap mouse buttons in specific sites

Tags: mouse, web-application, button-remapping

In using Lucid charts I'm finding that the mouse button mappings are frustrating. In Lucid, right-click drag moves the diagram around. No other app that I use has this button mapping, so daily I'm clicking the wrong button to drag. It is far from optimal.

Is there a way to make it so that I can, say, click a different button to drag. Lucid doesn't offer it such a configuration option. I'm picturing something like a browser extension that changes the key/button mappings per web app.

Comment: You're asking for a browser extension but you haven't even provided info about which browser(s) you're using. AHK could work if you need it to work on multiple.

Comment: @Destroy666 To save you and everyone trouble in the future, please presume that it's the most common of a given category (such as a chromium-based browser). If someone is using a thing that is out of the mainstream then they'll make it clear that that's a criterion.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools such as P. Gibbons' free [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) and [alternatives for Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-and-customizing-your-mouse-buttons-actions/) and [for all operating systems](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/) that can reassign mouse buttons with a number of profiles. From the [X-Mouse Button Control User Guide](https://dvps.highrez.co.uk/downloads/X-Mouse%20Button%20Control%20User%20Guide.pdf): "The Application/Window Profiles list contains all of the profiles you have created and assigned to various applications or windows." That implies that different apps can have the mouse operate in different ways (different profiles). One can also switch profiles with a key or button-click.

As with any software, check at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) before installing.